# upload multiple files to server, and write to database

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload, upload, multiple-forms

So at the moment I have the following code in my html `<input type="file" required required="required" name="image" multiple="">`

and then before I added the `mutliple=""` tag, this always worked for me,

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
{
$current_image=$_FILES['image']['name'];
$extension = substr(strrchr($current_image, '.'), 1);
if (($extension!= "png") && ($extension != "jpg")) 
{
die('Unknown extension');
}
$time = date("fYhis");
$new_image = $time . "." . $extension;
$destination="./../img/treatments/".$new_image;
$action = copy($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $destination);
```

but now that i am trying to upload multiple files I think I need to add an array to name them but I cannot figure it out, I don't want to change my code very much if I can.

Also at the moment the img is only one field on my database, how much of an issue is this?

**EDIT**

I found this code but cant seem to figure out how to implement it and make it work...

> After trying dozens of ways that are supposed to fix the wonkyness of the $_FILES array I didn't find any that could work with a input name like: userfile[christiaan][][][is][gaaf][]
>
> So I came up with this class

```
<?php
/**
 * A class that takes the pain out of the $_FILES array
 * @author Christiaan Baartse <christiaan@baartse.nl>
 */
class UploadedFiles extends ArrayObject
{
    public function current() {
        return $this->_normalize(parent::current());
    }

    public function offsetGet($offset) {
        return $this->_normalize(parent::offsetGet($offset));
    }

    protected function _normalize($entry) {
        if(isset($entry['name']) && is_array($entry['name'])) {
            $files = array();
            foreach($entry['name'] as $k => $name) {
                $files[$k] = array(
                    'name' => $name,
                    'tmp_name' => $entry['tmp_name'][$k],
                    'size' => $entry['size'][$k],
                    'type' => $entry['type'][$k],
                    'error' => $entry['error'][$k]
                );
            }
            return new self($files);
        }
        return $entry;
    }
    }
    ?>
```

> This allows you to access a file uploaded using the following inputtype
> `<input type="file" name="userfile[christiaan][][][is][gaaf][]" />`
> like

```
<?php
$files = new UploadedFiles($_FILES);
var_dump($files['userfile']['christiaan'][0][0]['is']['gaaf'][0]);
// or
foreach($files['userfile']['christiaan'][0][0]['is']['gaaf'] as $file) {
    var_dump($file);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this for you 
http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php

Comment: I found this one, but I am not sure how to implement it with my code, because I still want it to be named the same only with, lets say a _1, _2 etc at the end of the names...

Comment: I think you can edit $name try it and tell me what you found try it by appending this time().$name

Answer (score 0):

Try this (your problem seems in fact to be the totally missing understanding of how this all works in php, instead of some specific problem/bug/...):

whatever.php:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">
First file: <input type="file" name="uploads[]" /><br>
Second File: <input type="file" name="uploads[]" /><br>
Multiple files at once (firefox, chrome, ... not IE < 10): <input type="file" name="uploads_multiple[]" multiple="multiple" /><br>
<input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
<?php
print_r($_FILES);
```

Try this with different inputs (filesizes, missing files, ...) to see what you get from that in php. I think you'll benefit from this way more than if posted some finished code.

Edit: Also, DON'T use copy for this! Most of the time it just won't work, sometimes it might give unexpected results, and sometimes you'll just be opening a can of worms. There is a reason the function move_uploaded_file exists - USE IT!